# Youtube API: Include whether or not video has captions in a request to get related video of a video

Tags: youtube-api

The `videoCaption=closedCaption` request parameter is not working at all (try it out yourself here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). Is there any way around this FLAW in the Youtube API?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, here are the parameters I used:

> **part**: id,snippet
>
> **q**: puppies
>
> **type**: video
>
> **videoCaption**: closedCaption

Which returned the following video ids:

- CXE7IIuE1nw
- 0JboM-STb4E
- 1GJqfyzfCWU
- 5wdgrEGE50Q
- sQtYNOM0ew0

All of which have closed captions. Then I searched for ones with none, and to give an example:

- mRf3-JkwqfU

It has none. Perhaps there is an error in your code or a weird combination of your parameters to lead to this issue.

Comment: doesn't work when using /search/list for getting related videos (example: relatedToVideoId=0P2mzkF9xHg)

Comment: I've tested this and @user2568580 may be correct, this issue may be due to combination of parameters. Tried searching without `relatedToVideoId`, returned videos with closed captions. Tried searching with `relatedToVideoId`, return videos with and without closed caption (sometimes without closed caption). I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior but try [filing a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=0) to verify this behavior. Hope this helps.